# Convert raw query to django orm

Tags: python, django

I written this query in MySQL and I'm confused of conversion of this query to django orm

```
SELECT * FROM student.student_data 
where created_by in (select user_id from user_profile where user_location in(7, 8));
```

Comment: You can check this doc [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-sql-queries](Doc)

Comment: I know how to create orm queries but I'm little but confused about nested query

Answer (score -1):

This might help you

```
query = UserProfile.objects.filter(user_location__in = [7,8])
student_data = Student.objects.filter(created_by = query)
```

For more: [https://mattrobenolt.com/the-django-orm-and-subqueries/]